# Why can't I add another cardView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, android-cardview

I am creating a time table app. That app has an `add` button which adds new cardView - `row` - in the ArrayList `rows`. Before adding a new cardView I have one `if` condition that checks whether the previous `row`'s credentials were empty or not. If it is not empty then only the user could make another row. Each `row` has TextView and 2 EditTexts.

Right now, the code is unable to make another `row` even if the previous `row` was not empty. Whenever I add a new `row`, the app crashes and the error says, `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.matches(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`. The error is in the line that I have commented below in the `TimeTable` class. Why am I getting NullPointerException and how do I fix it?

Here is the `TimeTable` class -

```
    package com.example.timetable;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TimeTable extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    Button addBtn;

    ArrayList<row> rows = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.time_table);

        addBtn = findViewById(R.id.add);
        rows.add(new row());

        createRecyclerView();

        //adapter should come here

        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //I want check whether the last row is empty or not
                //the line below gives me the error
                if(rows.get(rows.size()-1).getTasksName().matches(" ") || rows.get(rows.size()-1).getHours() == 0) {

                    Toast.makeText(TimeTable.this, "Fill out previous row's content", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return; 
                }
                else {

                    rows.add(new row());
                    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(rows.size());
                    Log.i("Test", "new element has been added");

                }
            }
        });
        
    }
    
    
    public void createRecyclerView(){
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mAdapter = new Adapter(rows, TimeTable.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

Here is the code for `row` -

```
package com.example.timetable;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class row {

    int index;
    int hours;
    String tasksName;

    public row() {
        int i = index;
        int h = hours;
        String tN = tasksName;
    }

    public int getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public String getTasksName() {
        return tasksName;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public void setHours(int hours) {
        this.hours = hours;
    }

    public void setTasksName(String tasksName) {
        this.tasksName = tasksName;
    }
}
```

Here is the Adapter class -

```
package com.example.timetable;


import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.cellVH> {


    ArrayList<row> unitCell;
    Context context;

    public Adapter (ArrayList<row> oneCell, Context context){
        unitCell = oneCell;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public class cellVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView index;
        public EditText tasksName;
        public EditText totalHours;

        public cellVH(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            index = itemView.findViewById(R.id.index);
            tasksName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.taskName);
            totalHours = itemView.findViewById(R.id.totalHours);
        }
    }

     @NonNull

    /**
     * RecyclerView calls this method whenever it needs to create a new ViewHolder.
     * The method creates and initializes the ViewHolder and its associated View, but
     * does not fill in the view's contents—the ViewHolder has not yet been bound to
     * specific data.
     */
    @Override
    public cellVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.each_row, parent, false);
        cellVH cVH = new cellVH(v);
        return cVH;
    }

    /**
     * RecyclerView calls this method to associate a ViewHolder with data. The method fetches
     * the appropriate data and uses the data to fill in the view holder's layout. For example,
     * if the RecyclerView displays a list of names, the method might find the appropriate name
     * in the list and fill in the view holder's TextView widget.
     */

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull cellVH holder, int position) {
        holder.index.setText(String.valueOf(unitCell.get(position).getIndex()));
        holder.tasksName.setText(String.valueOf(unitCell.get(position).getTasksName()));
        holder.totalHours.setText(String.valueOf(unitCell.get(position).getHours()));
    }

    /**
     * RecyclerView calls this method to get the size of the data set. For example, in an address book
     * app, this might be the total number of addresses. RecyclerView uses this to determine when there
     * are no more items that can be displayed.
     */
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return unitCell.size();
    }


}
```

Edit -

Here is the error message -

```
2022-06-21 17:17:03.199 3242-3242/com.example.timetable E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.timetable, PID: 3242
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.matches(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.timetable.TimeTable$1.onClick(TimeTable.java:43)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7441)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1194)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7418)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:835)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28676)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Here is the .xml file of my `TimeTable` class -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".TimeTable">

    

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="+">

    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the .xml file cardView - `row` -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:contentPadding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/index"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.125"
            android:text="1."
            android:textAlignment="center">

        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/taskName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.625"
            android:hint="Enter Task's name"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck">

        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/totalHours"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:hint="Time"
            android:inputType="time">

        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: You should post the full stacktrace, too. At a glance, it looks like you're creating a new, empty `ArrayList`, calling it `rows`, then later this  code: `rows.get(rows.size()-1)` – wouldn't `rows.size()` return "0", and then "0-1" is "-1", and then you're calling `rows.get(-1)`?

Comment: Sure, I will add the stack trace as well. I have added an element in `rows` in my  `onCreate` method in `TimeTable` class, and then I perform `setOnClickListener`.

Comment: When does `setTasksName()` get called?

Comment: Haven't used any of the setters yet.

Comment: Try adding this right before the `if` statement: `System.out.println(rows.get(rows.size()-1).getTasksName())`

Comment: I tried adding this just before the if statement, but activity crashes and goes back to one of my previous activity (not mentioned in the code above). That is why, I cannot check `System.out.println(rows.get(rows.size()-1).getTasksName())`  because the stack trace doesn't show anything related to the TimeTable activity. But, if I put that line outside and before the `onClickListener`, the statement prints out  null

Comment: If that statement fails, try adding this one: `System.out.println(rows.get(rows.size()-1))`. Somewhere you’ve got a null, and these are suggestions to try exposing where.